# Check if value present in object

Tags: php

How do I check if neighborhood value is present in the object?

```
{
  "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "2900",
           "short_name" : "2900",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Ranch Road 620 North",
           "short_name" : "Ranch Rd 620 N",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Villas On Travis",
           "short_name" : "Villas On Travis",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Austin",
           "short_name" : "Austin",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Travis County",
           "short_name" : "Travis County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Texas",
           "short_name" : "TX",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "78734",
           "short_name" : "78734",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "2209",
           "short_name" : "2209",
           "types" : [ "postal_code_suffix" ]
        }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I've tried

```
if ($jsonarray->results[0]->address_components[2]->types == 'neighborhood') {
  $neighborhood = $jsonarray->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name;
}
```

Comment: Anywhere in the object, or in a specific place?

Comment: types is still an array so dont you need to say types[0]

Comment: There's only one place: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=30.560030000000,-97.691430000000

Comment: Thanks @Don't Panic. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: You will probably want to increase your sample size. Different queries will return *very* different results. You cannot expect to find "neighborhood" always as the third component of the first result. You will have to iterate each result and each component within each result and pick and choose your data from it; not the other way around.

Comment: @deceze https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=30.560030000000,-97.691430000000

Comment: @santa https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=35.6895,139.6917

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an array:

```
if (in_array('neighborhood', $jsonarray->results[0]->address_components[2]->types)) {
  $neighborhood = $jsonarray->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name;
}
```

So to check them all, if's that's the intent, if there will only be one `neighborhood`:

```
foreach($jsonarray->results[0]->address_components as $array) {
    if (in_array('neighborhood', $array->types)) {
      $neighborhood = $array->long_name;
      break;
    }
}
```

Or to get a `$neighborhood` array of all found:

```
foreach($jsonarray->results[0]->address_components as $array) {
    if (in_array('neighborhood', $array->types)) {
      $neighborhood[] = $array->long_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: While not technically incorrect, I doubt it's sane to approach this so directly. Some looping is probably in order…

Comment: Yes, it was an example to expand upon.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if ($jsonarray->results[0]->address_components[2]->types[0] == 'neighborhood') {
  $neighborhood = $jsonarray->results[0]->address_components[2]->long_name;
 }
```

Comment: Is there any guarantee whatsoever that the value will always be in exactly that place…?

Comment: but whats the guarantee its in address_components[2], based on his code that is where he is looking for it, AbraCadavers way is more absolute though